# Неправильно создаются две и более таблицы в одном документе Word через VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Для моих задач мне требуется создать несколько таблиц в документе Word средствами VBA через Excel.
Вот мой код

```
sub mainProcedure
    Dim wApp As word.Application
    Set wApp = createWordApplication
    Dim wDoc As word.Document
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add
    Call createTables(wDoc, wApp)
end sub

sub createTables(wDoc as word.document, wApp as word.application)
dim table as word.table
'!!!
Set table = wDoc.Tables.Add(wDoc.Range(0, 0), 5, 5) 'Вот здесь и вся проблема. Помогите решить
'!!!
'Пробовал делать ещё таким образом
'set table = wDoc.Tables.add(wApp.Selection.Range,5,5)
table.Borders.enable = True
end sub

Function createWordApplication() As word.Application
    Dim wApp As New word.Application
    wApp.visible = True
    Set createWordApplication = wApp
End Function
```

В чем заключается проблема: **проблема в том, что при исполнении строчки с кодом создания таблицы (set table = wDoc.Tables.add(wDoc.Range(0,0),5,5)) вторая таблица создаётся в первой колонке первого столбца уже существующей таблицы.** То есть первая таблица создаётся, в неё заносятся данные. Но при создании ещё одной таблицы в этом wDoc она вставляется не строчкой ниже существующей таблицы, а прямо в саму существующую таблицу. Я полагаю, что это связано с Range. Я пробовал делать разными способами в процессе дебага, но ничего не получилось. **Подскажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы новые таблицы вставлялись в конец документа?**
Пока что проблему решил тем, что создаю несколько wApp и связанные с ним wDoc и на каждом из них создаю таблицы. Конечно вариант не очень. Нужно, чтобы на одном wApp и wDoc было несколько таблиц, текст и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант без Selection. Базируется на свойстве [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/word.document.content), представляющем собой основную историю документа. Комментарии в коде.

```
Option Explicit

Function createWordApplication(Optional Visible As Boolean = True) As Word.Application ' видимость окна приложения делаем как опциональный аргумент, по умолчанию - видимо
    On Error Resume Next
    Set createWordApplication = GetObject(, "Word.Application") ' попытка подключиться к уже открытому Word, чтобы не дублировать
    On Error GoTo 0
    If createWordApplication Is Nothing Then ' если открытого Word нет, то запускаем приложение
        Set createWordApplication = New Word.Application
        createWordApplication.Visible = Visible
    End If
End Function

Sub createTable(wd As Word.Document, Optional tableCaption As String = "")
    Dim start As Word.Range, table As Word.table
    wd.Content.InsertParagraphAfter ' вставить параграф в конце текста
    If tableCaption <> "" Then      ' если параметр заголовка таблицы не пуст, то 
        wd.Content.InsertAfter tableCaption   ' напечатать заголовок 
        wd.Content.InsertParagraphAfter       ' добавить еще параграф после
    End If
    Set table = wd.Tables.Add(wd.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range, 5, 5) 'добавить таблицу в последний параграф
    With table.Borders  ' оформить границы таблицы (есть множество вариантов границ https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/word.wdlinestyle)
        .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    End With
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Dim Word As Word.Application, wd As Word.Document, i As Integer
    Set Word = createWordApplication
    
    Set wd = Word.Documents.Add 
    For i = 1 To 10 ' создаем 10 таблиц одну под другой, добавляя между ними опциональный заголовок
        createTable wd, "Таблица № " & i
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я понял как можно управлять содержанием в документе. 
Отличное решение, красивый код!

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил! Покопался в интернете и нашёл следующее:

```
wApp.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
```

Я так понимаю данный метод EndKey переносит выделение до конца страницы. Далее делаем

```
wApp.Selection.TypeText vbNewLine
```

И можем создавать новую таблицу.
Решение работает, но насколько оно правильное не могу сказать. Буду рад увидеть и другие способы с пояснением решение данной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя первые параметр Range должен указывать на место, где будет создаваться таблица. В коде жёстко задано 0,0 и он всегда пытается создать таблицу в верхнем левом углу
Поменяй на

```
Set table = wDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=wDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range, NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=5, _
                      DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
                      AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
```

Как-то так.
Вторая таблица будет создаваться ниже. Но в таком варианте она будет приклеена к верхней таблице. Нужно создать ещё одну пустую строку, наверное, до вызова этой команды второй раз, чтобы между таблицами был промежуток.